# Postgresql 9.1 dependency issue

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I use **Ubuntu 12.04** and have just ran

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

...and ended up with this error message...

```
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of postgresql-9.1:
 postgresql-client-9.1 (9.1.7-0ubuntu12.04) breaks postgresql-9.1 (<< 9.1.7-0ubuntu12.04) and is installed.
  Version of postgresql-9.1 to be configured is 9.1.6-1~precise2.
dpkg: error processing postgresql-9.1 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 postgresql-9.1
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I see that it is a dependency issue but **I don't know how to resolve it**... I ran sudo apt-get -f install and it resolved nothing...

*sidenote: I installed postgres from repository ppa:pitti/postgresql, if that matters somehow.*

Comment: Just a note: Ask on superuser.com instead.

Comment: Since this question appears when searching for this specific problem, I thought I'd share the question that resolved it for me. See if [my askubuntu question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/233061/apt-get-upgrade-stuck-on-postgresql-dependency) helps at all.